# Count the number of repeated letters from the array of each string

Tags: javascript

i have an array of strings with duplicated letters , Now i want to count the number of duplicated letters from each string and need to create a separate object for each string.
The given array :

```
let ArrOfStrs = ["aaabbbccc", "dddeeefff", "ggghhhiii", "jkl"]
```

what i have tried :

```
var obj={}
var repeats=[];
for(let i=0; i< ArrOfStrs.length; i++) {
    for(let x = 0;  x < ArrOfStrs[i].length; x++) {
        var l = ArrOfStrs[i].charAt(x);
        obj[l] = (!obj.hasOwnProperty(l) ? 1 : obj[l] + 1);
    }
}
repeats.push(obj);
console.log(repeats);
```

Actual output :

```
 { a: 3, b: 3, c: 3, d: 3, e: 3, f: 3, g: 3, h: 3, i: 3, j: 1, k: 1, l: 1 }
```

Expected output :

```
 [{a:3,b:3,c:3}, {d:3,e:3,f:3},{g:3,h:3,i:3},{j:1,k:1,l:1}]
```

Could some one help for better approach to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: put `repeats.push(obj);` immediately after the second `for`, but still inside the first `for` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yx749uqz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 mistakes :

1. You are keeping a common object `obj` and making changes to it. Infact `obj` will be different for every string.
2. You are not pushing `obj` into your result array for every iteration. You are doing it in the end, hence you have only one item in your array.

Making minimal changes, your code can be fixed:

```js
let ArrOfStrs = ["aaabbbccc", "dddeeefff", "ggghhhiii", "jkl"]

var repeats=[];
for(let i=0; i< ArrOfStrs.length; i++) {
    var obj={}
    for(let x = 0;  x < ArrOfStrs[i].length; x++) {
        var l = ArrOfStrs[i].charAt(x);
        obj[l] = (!obj.hasOwnProperty(l) ? 1 : obj[l] + 1);
    }
    repeats.push(obj);
}

console.log(repeats);
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array from an existing one
- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert an array to a different type (Object)
- [Spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert String to Array

```js
const arrOfStrs = ["aaabbbccc", "dddeeefff", "ggghhhiii", "jkl"];

const counted = arrOfStrs.map(str => [...str].reduce((o, v) => {
  o[v] ??= 0    // set default count to 0 (if not exists)
  o[v]++        // increment count
  return o;
}, {}));

console.log(counted);
```

***Additional read:***

- [Nullish coalescent operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Variant:

```js
const arrOfStrs = ["aaabbbccc", "dddeeefff", "ggghhhiii", "jkl"];
const counted = arrOfStrs.map(s => [...s].reduce((o, v) => (o[v] ??= 0, o[v]++, o), {}));

console.log(counted);
```